# what is the "attribute" of a pthread mutex?

Tags: attributes, pthreads, mutex

The function pthread_mutex_init allows you to specify a pointer to an attribute. But I have yet to find a good explanation of what pthread attributes are. I have always just supplied NULL. Is there a use to this argument?

The documentation, for those of you who forget it:

> PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT(3)    BSD Library
>   Functions Manual
>   PTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT(3)
>
> NAME
>        pthread_mutex_init -- create a mutex
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <pthread.h>
>
>  int
>  pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
>      const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The pthread_mutex_init() function creates a new mutex, with attributes
>   specified
>        with attr.  If attr is NULL, the default attributes are used.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The best place to find that information is from the POSIX standards pages.

A `NULL` mutex attribute gives you an implementation defined default attribute. If you want to know what you can do with attributes, check out the [following reference](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html#tag_13_35) and follow the `pthread_mutexattr_*` links in the `SEE ALSO` section. Usually, the default is a sensible set of attributes but it may vary between platforms, so I prefer to explicitly create mutexes with known attributes (better for portability).

This is for issue 7 of the standard, 1003.1-2008. The starting point for that is [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Clicking on `Headers` in the bottom left will allow you to navigate to the specific functionality (including `pthreads.h`).

The attributes allow you to set or get:

- the [type](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html#) (deadlocking, deadlock-detecting, recursive, etc).
- the [robustness](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html#) (what happens when you acquire a mutex and the original owner died while possessing it).
- the [process-shared attribute](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html#) (for sharing a mutex across process boundaries).
- the [protocol](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.html#) (how a thread behaves in terms of priority when a higher-priority thread wants the mutex).
- the [priority ceiling](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling.html#) (the priority at which the critical section will run, a way of preventing priority inversion).

And, for completeness, there's the [init and destroy calls](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_destroy.html#) as well, not directly related to a specific attribute but used to create them.

Answer (score 7):

All mutex attributes are set in a mutex attribute object by a function of the form:

```
int pthread_mutexattr_setname(pthread_attr_t *attr, Type t);
```

All mutex attributes are retrieved from a mutex attribute object by a function of the form:

```
int pthread_mutexattr_getname(const pthread_attr_t *attr, Type *t);
```

where name and Type are defined as in the table below:

```
Type and Name   Description and Value(s)
int protocol    Define the scheduling classes for mutex locks 
                PTHREAD_PRIO_NONE,PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT,
                PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT

int pshared Defines whether a mutex is shared with other processes. 
                PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE

int prioceiling Used for mutex attribute priority ceiling values. 
                See POSIX.1 section 13

int type    Application defined mutex locking
                PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL,PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE,
                PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK,PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 3):

If you scroll down the function listing for [`<pthread.h>`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread.h.html), you will find a bunch of `pthread_mutexattr_...` functions, including an `init`, `destroy` and functions to set various attributes of a mutex. When you pass `NULL`, the mutex is created with suitable defaults for all these attributes, but if you need to modify specific attributes, you can construct a `pthread_mutexattr_t` structure and pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Applying NULL to this argument implies using the default argument.
So for some reasons you could want to change these default settings (using pthread_mutexattr_init).

The documentation explains all you need about these mutex settings.

Comment: If the documentation were at all useful, the question wouldn't need to be asked. :-) I've been trying for the better part of an hour to find the answers to the same question, before I stumbled onto this one.