# Using mutexes/semaphores with processes

Tags: linux, process, ipc, mutex

Almost all the code and tutorials that I have read online so far involve using mutexes and semaphores for synchronisation amongst threads. Can they be used to synchronise amongst processes?

I'd like to write code that looks like this:

```
void compute_and_print() {
   // acquire mutex
   // critical section
   // release mutex
}

void main() {
int pid = fork();
if ( pid == 0 ) {
  // do something
  compute_and_print();
}
else {
  // do something
  compute_and_print();
}
}
```

- Could someone point me towards similar code that does this?
- I understand that different processes have different address spaces, but I wonder if the above would be different address spaces, however, wouldn't the mutex refer to the same kernel object?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. There are many ways to synchronize different processes. Perhaps the most popular solutions for mutual exclusion in this field are [System V IPC semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) and [atomic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_operation) on [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). I recommend you read chapter 5 of David A Ruslin's book called [Interprocess Communication Mechanisms](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html), or better yet - the whole book.

As for your second question, most modern operating systems on commodity hardware would place processes in different address spaces, though it is also possible for processes to share the same address space (see [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [Memory Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection)). Either way, if IPC mechanism is handled by the kernel, then two processes would refer to the same "kernel object", as you said. In cases where mutual exclusion is implemented (almost) without the kernel (like spin locks of some sort that use "shared memory"), both processes would refer to the same physical memory even though their virtual addresses for that memory might be different.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, POSIX (and linux) support *two* separate families of semaphores that have two different interfaces and methods of usage.

There is the older SysV semaphores consisting of `semget`, `semop`, `semctl` and (somewhat optionally) `ftok`.

The more modern "posix" semaphores consist of `sem_open/sem_init`, `sem_wait`, `sem_post`, `sem_close` and `sem_unlink`.

The setup/usage regimes and capabilities are different enough that it is worth familiarizing yourself with both to see what is better for your use case.

You can also use process shared mutexes from the pthreads package.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [System V IPC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node21.html) You would probably use a semaphore to synchronize between processes.

Here is a nice introduction to [Sys V IPC in Linux](http://fscked.org/writings/SHM/shm-5.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want named mutex/semaphore's. Take a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389730/is-it-possible-to-use-mutex-in-multiprocessing-case-on-linux-unix) that describes some points. Here's an [IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/apis/users_56.htm) describing the use of `pthread_mutexattr_setname_np`. One thing to note that named mutex's in Linux are not 100% portable (i.e. it MIGHT work on Ubuntu but NOT on CentOS, etc. etc.), so you'll need to be sure your platform supports it. If a named mutex is not available on your system, you could use named pipes with some wait conditions or even local sockets. As another answer points out is SysV IPC.

The biggest question you'll need to answer first is how 'cross-linux-platform' compatible do you want your app to be.