# What is equivalent of boost interprocess named_mutex in STL

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

I've an application with boost named_mutex implemented to lock multiple modules in a C++ project (Visual Studio). I need to remove all boost dependencies at all costs.

Is there any other way I can implement it? If possible in STL
btw, I'm using C++11

Comment: The STL is from 1994, when nobody did anything in parallel. The C++ standard library  from 2014 also does not contain a notion of "process" or "inter-process"; you'll need an external library.

Comment: "I need to remove all boost dependencies at all costs." - why? Is your project lead a psychopath?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own version control system?

Comment: @KerrekSB: "1994, when nobody did anything in parallel" - really? I guess my Amiga must have been a dream then. Along with Linux and Windows NT, and various flavours of Unix dating back to the 60s.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Running an Amiga and a Windows NT box next to each other doesn't count as "parallelism" :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, but running multi-threaded programs (or multiple communicating processes) on either of those, or on the many other pre-emptive multitasking systems which were common at the time, most certainly does. The STL didn't include concurrency because it was outside its scope, not because no-one was doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none.

You'll have to drop down to platform specific APIs

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx
- [Is it possible to use mutex in multiprocessing case on Linux/UNIX ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389730/is-it-possible-to-use-mutex-in-multiprocessing-case-on-linux-unix/9426906#9426906)

Etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at Intel's tbb library. It is very fast and created to help with parallel execution.

https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/synchronization/mutexes.htm