# c++ multiprocess writing a unique file

Tags: c++

I have a process which creates multiple fork processes and each forked process 
 creates a file with the same name. But the requirement is to create only one file by any of the forked processes.

Can you please suggest how to make sure file is created by only one process.

I tried to check if the file exists before writing a file but it is not working as multiple processes are getting pass beyond that check.

Comment: c or c++? please choose

Comment: Check the return value from `fork` to see which process is the parent and which is the child, then only have one of them do the file creation depending on that value.

Comment: There can be multiple child , each child creating same file.

Comment: what are you going to do with the file after creation? do you need to write to it, or just need it to exist?

Comment: @slawekwin after each child process exit then I will read from the file.

Comment: That's also what parallel file systems are for. Especially writing to the same file.

Comment: XY problem most likely. Why doesn't it matter *which* child writes the file? Please explain what you're implementing exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please suggest how to make sure file is created by only one process.

1. Each of the concurrent processes (or threads) creates its own file in the target directory with a unique temporary filename with [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html).
2. Then the process [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html)s that file to the target filename. [Renaming is atomic](https://rcrowley.org/2010/01/06/things-unix-can-do-atomically.html) and either succeeds or fails. If it fails, then another process already created the file. In this case the temporary file can be removed and the file with the target filename should be opened instead.

Comment: I solved it using `fopen` with `wx` mode similar to `open` with `O_EXCL`.

Comment: @EmptyData With `fopen(..., "wx")` you do not have a chance to initialize the file before renaming it to its target name.

Answer (score 0):

You might open the file in the parent process *before* forking. Each child then can, according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91061) answer, just re-use the file descriptor and you should be fine.

Of course, you'd still need some means to synchronise your different processes such that writes to the file are interleaved properly (one process writing `AB` and the other one `C` resulting in `ABC` or `CAB`, but *not* `ACB`...). Doing so is easier with threads, so if you *can* use them you might prefer them. Otherwise, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9426906/1312382) answer might be of interest to you.

*Edit (according to new comments to question):* If I understand correctly, you want to do the following:

- Parent process creates several child processes.
- Each child writes some information to a file.
- After each or all children having terminated, parent reads back the information from files.

You might do the following then:

1. Parent process opens a new temporary file with with arbitrary name for each child - right before forking. This way, according to above, parent and child have the same file descriptors available.
2. After forking, child process uses the file descriptor to write it's information to, parent process pushes the descriptor to e. g. a `std::vector` or, if more suitable, a `std::map` mapping PID to FD.
3. Parent process waits for children, on termination uses the file descriptors stored to read information back.

Have you considered using [pipes](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) instead? They might be the better alternative...