# What is the "default mutex attributes" of the pthread_mutex**

Tags: linux, attributes, pthreads, mutex

In man page for interface like `pthread_mutex_init`,

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
          const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
```

It says "**If attr is NULL, the default mutex attributes are used...**", and `the default mutex attributes` are mentioned many times, and it is also mentioned in the book `The Linux Programming Interface`, but it is never explained in detail anywhere, I googled and no result.

There is one post [what is the "attribute" of a pthread mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252005/what-is-the-attribute-of-a-pthread-mutex), and it mentioned "Usually, the default is a sensible set of attributes but it may vary between platforms", but it is not what I want, I want more details.

So, what is exactly the `default mutex attributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_mutexattr_t` is an opaque type (you never modify it directly) that's accessed via various `pthread_mutexattr_get*()/set*()` functions. Unless the documentation for those functions specify a default, then the default is up to the implementation, and you can't rely on a particular value.

You could follow the links to the various `pthread_mutexattr_get*()` functions in POSIX.1-2008 [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/basedefs/pthread.h.html) and look for default values (which also apply when you pass `NULL` for the attributes). Here's some choice quotes:

[pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.html):

> The default value of the attribute shall be PTHREAD_PRIO_NONE.

[pthread_mutexattr_gettype()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_gettype.html):

> The default value of the type attribute is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT.

[pthread_mutexattr_getpshared()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html):

> The default value of the attribute shall be PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE.

[pthread_mutexattr_getrobust()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html):

> PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED ... This is the default value.

The non-type attributes are kinda obscure though.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for [pthread_mutexattr_settype](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_settype) gets us started.  It says "The default value of the type attribute is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT."  Unfortunately it goes on to say that PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT isn't really defined and could be anything.

I wrote a short C++ program to take a closer look:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int, char**)
{
  std::cout<<"PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = "<<PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL<<std::endl
       <<"PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK = "<<PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK<<std::endl
       <<"PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE = "<<PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE<<std::endl
       <<"PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT = "<<PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT<<std::endl;

}
```

That gave me the following output:

```
PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = 0
PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK = 2
PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE = 1
PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT = 0
```

So at least on my system the default is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, i.e. "fast" / non-recursive.